# Why tasks are stuck in None state in Airflow 1.10.2 after a trigger_dag

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I have a dummy DAG that I want to start episodically by setting its `start_date` to `today` and letting its schedul interval to `daily`

here is the DAG code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- airflow: DAG -*-
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger("DummyDAG")


def execute_python_function():
    logging.info("HEY YO !!!")
    return True


dag = DAG(dag_id='dummy_dag',
          start_date=datetime.today())

start = DummyOperator(task_id='start', dag=dag)
end = DummyOperator(task_id='end', dag=dag)

py_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='exec_function',
                             python_callable=execute_python_function,
                             dag=dag)

start >> py_operator >> end
```

In Airflow 1.9.0, when I do an `airflow trigger_dag -e 20190701` the DAG Run is created, Tasks Instances are created, scheduled and executed.

However, in Airflow 1.10.2 the DAG Run is created Task Instances too but they are stuck in `None` state.

for both versions the depends_on_past is `False`

Here are the details of the `start` task in Airflow 1.9.0 (it is executed, with success, after some time)

```
Task Instance Details

Dependencies Blocking Task From Getting Scheduled

Dependency:         Reason
Dagrun Running:     Task instance's dagrun was not in the 'running' state but in the state 'success'.
Task Instance State:    Task is in the 'success' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.
Execution Date:     The execution date is 2019-07-10T00:00:00 but this is before the task's start date 2019-07-11T08:45:18.230876.
Execution Date:     The execution date is 2019-07-10T00:00:00 but this is before the task's DAG's start date 2019-07-11T08:45:18.230876.

Task instance attribute

Attribute   Value
dag_id  dummy_dag
duration    None
end_date    2019-07-10 16:32:10.372976
execution_date  2019-07-10 00:00:00
generate_command    <function generate_command at 0x7fc9fcc85b90>
hostname    airflow-worker-5dc5b999b6-2l5cp
is_premature    False
job_id  None
key     ('dummy_dag', 'start', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 10, 0, 0))
log     <logging.Logger object at 0x7fca014e7f10>
log_filepath    /home/airflow/gcs/logs/dummy_dag/start/2019-07-10T00:00:00.log
log_url     https://i39907f7014685e91-tp.appspot.com/admin/airflow/log?dag_id=dummy_dag&task_id=start&execution_date=2019-07-10T00:00:00
logger  <logging.Logger object at 0x7fca014e7f10>
mark_success_url    https://i39907f7014685e91-tp.appspot.com/admin/airflow/success?task_id=start&dag_id=dummy_dag&execution_date=2019-07-10T00:00:00&upstream=false&downstream=false
max_tries   0
metadata    MetaData(bind=None)
next_try_number     2
operator    None
pid     180712
pool    None
previous_ti     None
priority_weight     3
queue   default
queued_dttm     None
run_as_user     None
start_date  2019-07-10 16:32:08.483531
state   success
task    <Task(DummyOperator): start>
task_id     start
test_mode   False
try_number  2
unixname    airflow

Task Attributes

Attribute   Value
adhoc   False
dag     <DAG: dummy_dag>
dag_id  dummy_dag
depends_on_past     False
deps    set([<TIDep(Not In Retry Period)>, <TIDep(Previous Dagrun State)>, <TIDep(Trigger Rule)>])
downstream_list     [<Task(PythonOperator): exec_function>]
downstream_task_ids     ['exec_function']
email   None
email_on_failure    True
email_on_retry  True
end_date    None
execution_timeout   None
log     <logging.Logger object at 0x7fc9e2085350>
logger  <logging.Logger object at 0x7fc9e2085350>
max_retry_delay     None
on_failure_callback     None
on_retry_callback   None
on_success_callback     None
owner   Airflow
params  {}
pool    None
priority_weight     1
priority_weight_total   3
queue   default
resources   {'disk': {'_qty': 512, '_units_str': 'MB', '_name': 'Disk'}, 'gpus': {'_qty': 0, '_units_str': 'gpu(s)', '_name': 'GPU'}, 'ram': {'_qty': 512, '_units_str': 'MB', '_name': 'RAM'}, 'cpus': {'_qty': 1, '_units_str': 'core(s)', '_name': 'CPU'}}
retries     0
retry_delay     0:05:00
retry_exponential_backoff   False
run_as_user     None
schedule_interval   1 day, 0:00:00
sla     None
start_date  2019-07-11 08:45:18.230876
task_concurrency    None
task_id     start
task_type   DummyOperator
template_ext    []
template_fields     ()
trigger_rule    all_success
ui_color    #e8f7e4
ui_fgcolor  #000
upstream_list   []
upstream_task_ids   []
wait_for_downstream     False
```

Details of the start task in Airflow 1.10.2

```
Task Instance Details
Dependencies Blocking Task From Getting Scheduled

Dependency  Reason
Execution Date  The execution date is 2019-07-11T00:00:00+00:00 but this is before the task's start date 2019-07-11T08:53:32.593360+00:00.
Execution Date  The execution date is 2019-07-11T00:00:00+00:00 but this is before the task's DAG's start date 2019-07-11T08:53:32.593360+00:00.


Task Instance Attributes

Attribute   Value
dag_id  dummy_dag
duration    None
end_date    None
execution_date  2019-07-11T00:00:00+00:00
executor_config     {}
generate_command    <function generate_command at 0x7f4621301578>
hostname    
is_premature    False
job_id  None
key     ('dummy_dag', 'start', <Pendulum [2019-07-11T00:00:00+00:00]>, 1)
log     <logging.Logger object at 0x7f4624883350>
log_filepath    /home/airflow/gcs/logs/dummy_dag/start/2019-07-11T00:00:00+00:00.log
log_url     https://a15d189066a5c65ee-tp.appspot.com/admin/airflow/log?dag_id=dummy_dag&task_id=start&execution_date=2019-07-11T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00
logger  <logging.Logger object at 0x7f4624883350>
mark_success_url    https://a15d189066a5c65ee-tp.appspot.com/admin/airflow/success?task_id=start&dag_id=dummy_dag&execution_date=2019-07-11T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&upstream=false&downstream=false
max_tries   0
metadata    MetaData(bind=None)
next_try_number     1
operator    None
pid     None
pool    None
previous_ti     None
priority_weight     3
queue   default
queued_dttm     None
raw     False
run_as_user     None
start_date  None
state   None
task    <Task(DummyOperator): start>
task_id     start
test_mode   False
try_number  1
unixname    airflow


Task Attributes


Attribute   Value
adhoc   False
dag     <DAG: dummy_dag>
dag_id  dummy_dag
depends_on_past     False
deps    set([<TIDep(Previous Dagrun State)>, <TIDep(Trigger Rule)>, <TIDep(Not In Retry Period)>])
downstream_list     [<Task(PythonOperator): exec_function>]
downstream_task_ids     set(['exec_function'])
email   None
email_on_failure    True
email_on_retry  True
end_date    None
execution_timeout   None
executor_config     {}
inlets  []
lineage_data    None
log     <logging.Logger object at 0x7f460b467e10>
logger  <logging.Logger object at 0x7f460b467e10>
max_retry_delay     None
on_failure_callback     None
on_retry_callback   None
on_success_callback     None
outlets     []
owner   Airflow
params  {}
pool    None
priority_weight     1
priority_weight_total   3
queue   default
resources   {'disk': {'_qty': 512, '_units_str': 'MB', '_name': 'Disk'}, 'gpus': {'_qty': 0, '_units_str': 'gpu(s)', '_name': 'GPU'}, 'ram': {'_qty': 512, '_units_str': 'MB', '_name': 'RAM'}, 'cpus': {'_qty': 1, '_units_str': 'core(s)', '_name': 'CPU'}}
retries     0
retry_delay     0:05:00
retry_exponential_backoff   False
run_as_user     None
schedule_interval   1 day, 0:00:00
sla     None
start_date  2019-07-11T08:53:32.593360+00:00
task_concurrency    None
task_id     start
task_type   DummyOperator
template_ext    []
template_fields     ()
trigger_rule    all_success
ui_color    #e8f7e4
ui_fgcolor  #000
upstream_list   []
upstream_task_ids   set([])
wait_for_downstream     False
weight_rule     downstream
```

Comment: Any errors in scheduler logs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IMO it's not a problem of the version. If you check the logs, you will see the messages like:

> Execution Date:
>   The execution date is 2019-07-10T00:00:00 but this is ***before the task's start date*** 2019-07-11T08:45:18.230876.

The execution date is the one you put in `trigger_dag` command whereas the start date of your DAG is changing because Python's  `datetime.today()` returns the current time. To see that, you can do:

```
airflow@e3bc9a0a7a3e:~$ airflow trigger_dag dummy_dag -e 20190702
```

And later go to http://localhost:8080/admin/airflow/task?dag_id=dummy_dag&task_id=start&execution_date=2019-07-02T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00 (or any corresponding URL) and refresh the page. You should see `Dependency > Execution date` changing every time.

In your case it will be problematic since you're trying to trigger a DAG from the past. A better way is to specify a static date or use any of Airflow's util methods to figure it out:

```
dag = DAG(dag_id='dummy_dag',
          start_date=datetime(2019, 7, 11, 0, 0))
```

Otherwise, if you want to reprocess historical data, you can use [`airflow backfill`](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#backfill)

---

**update**

## Running DAGs on demand

After clarifications from comments, we found another way to trigger a DAG on demand with the property `schedule_interval=None`.

Comment: I have the same logs in Airflow 1.9.2 `Execution Date:     The execution date is 2019-07-10T00:00:00 but this is before the task's start date 2019-07-11T08:45:18.230876.
Execution Date:     The execution date is 2019-07-10T00:00:00 but this is before the task's DAG's start date 2019-07-11T08:45:18.230876.
` but the task is still scheduled and executed after some time. I purposely specified the start date to `datetime.today()` in order to launch DAG Runs episodically. If I didn't do so (static start date) the scheduler would have created DAG Runs every day (the default schedule interval)

Comment: OK, I will downgrade my version and retest. Otherwise, if you want to run a DAG periodically, you can also use `schedule_interval=None` and execute it on demand.

Comment: Indeed, it was scheduled on 1.9.0 (1.9.2 doesn't exist)! After a quick research, I found a JIRA that could change the behavior - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1837. I haven't got the details yet but not sure for that. If you want to search, there are a list of CHANGELONG https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt

Comment: Putting `schedule_interval=None` was the way to go. I achieved the same behavior as with using `airflow trigger_dag` with `start_date=datetime.today()` in Airflow 1.9.0. You can add that as a response and I'll accept it.

Comment: I had this same issue and it was because my default_args end_date was accidentally before the start_date

Answer (score 0):

If it's a subdag that you are trying to unpause, you need to go to the `Logs` tab. There, at the top-right corner, you will have the `Pause/Unpause` button.